# Fastest creation of new Date

Tags: javascript

I need a `new Date()` in my code and absolutely don't care with which date/time it will be created, because I will set date and time afterwards. I just need a new object. How to do that? Because `new Date()` will check the actual time. Is there some default date that I can create?

Comment: Why do you want to create a Date object before you know what you want it to be?

Comment: You could do `new Date(0)` but I doubt that's any faster. No matter what, it's going to have to create the internal structure of a Date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this variant:
    `new Date(0)`

From this source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

> JavaScript Date objects can only be instantiated by calling JavaScript
>   Date as a constructor: calling it as a regular function (i.e. without
>   the new operator) will return a string rather than a Date object;
>   unlike other JavaScript object types, JavaScript Date objects have no
>   literal syntax.
>
> If no arguments are provided, the constructor creates a JavaScript
>   Date object for the current date and time according to system
>   settings.

It means that `0` argument can really improve performance.

Comment: Here's a measurement of that performance difference: https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/ShowResult/5146 Note however, that even the slower method of using `new Date()` was able to get 5 million operations per second, which should be fast enough for almost any purpose.

Comment: Agree, it's really can't create any performance problem in almost every situation.